# Microsoft Solver Foundation UnsolvableModelException

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I am trying to solve an LP(a network problem) using Microsoft Solver Foundation. My code is in C#. I get the following error:
*UnsolvableModelException was unhandled. The solver(s) threw an exception while solving the model.*
But when I solve the same problem on a smaller sized network, I don't get this error. So is the error coming because the number of constraints and variables is too large? What is the reason for the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to show your full code..

Answer (score 1):

Number of constraints and/or variables might be the problem. Which edition of SF do you use? You can find more about editions related constraints [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524499%28v=vs.93%29.aspx). Also, you can experience the same problem if you use Gurobi Optimizer through Solver Foundation for large scale problems.